# PHP rename function error

Tags: php, rename

I am trying to rename a file after getting the file name using basename(). I am getting an error saying 'cannot find the file specified'.
My code is :

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";

$base_name = basename($_FILES["file_to_upload"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir.$base_name;//specifies the path of the file to be 
uploaded.
$image_extention = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

//rename the file
$rename_file_name = rename($base_name,'Image_1');
dd($rename_file_name);
```

When I run the code i get the following error:

> Warning: rename(RageFace.jpg,Image_1): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\file_upload_handle.php on line 23
>
> bool(false)

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the file instead of just the `basename()`?

Comment: If you [**read the manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) it will show that you need to give ***the full path to the file*** rather than just the file name, unless the file just happens to be in the **current working directory** , which would be unwise for uploaded files

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified" seems pretty clear to me. Check your path.

Comment: @kerbholz I did not try to give the full path before, I have given now and it's working.

Comment: @Martin Thanks. Your comment helped me understand the problem and my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

changing name while moving

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_to_upload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);
```